# Regex : extract the biggest number from x to y figures

Tags: regex

I have an Url formatted as follow : https://www.mywebsite.com/subdomain/123456789.htm. I know that the webpage number is built with exactly 9 or 10 digits. I would like to extract this number using a Regex.

The Regex I use to perform this operation is :

*^https://www.mywebsite.com/[A-Za-z0-9_.-~/]+([0-9]{9,10}).htm$*

The problem is that when the number is 10 digits long, I get a match which is good but only the last 9 digits are captured. For example :  https://www.mywebsite.com/subdomain/1234567890.htm captures 234567890 only.

I could easily create two regexes (one with 9 digits and one with 10) and take the longest number if both matches, but is there any elegant way to solve this problem using Regex?

**EDIT**

Following remarks which have been made below,  there is actually a mistake in my original Regex : the first character group matches the first digit of the 10, and leaves only the 9 others for the capturing group. I've added a screenshot below.  Adding a forward slash to the Regex before the capturing group solved the issue, thanks!

[image: Wrongly formatted Regex]

Comment: Add matching the forward slash before the digits `^https://www\.mywebsite\.com/[A-Za-z0-9_.~/-]+/([0-9]{9,10})\.htm$` https://regex101.com/r/rDUgcV/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character class `[A-Za-z0-9_.-~/]+` matches all the character that follow until the end of the line.

This part `([0-9]{9,10}).` will then backtrack until it can match the resulting digits, which it can starting from 9 digits and that will be in the capturing group.

**Note** to either escape the hyphen `\-` or place it at the start or end of the character class or else it could possible match a range.

One option is to use a word bounary `\b` before matching the digits

```
^https://www\.mywebsite\.com/[A-Za-z0-9_.~/-]+\b([0-9]{9,10})\.htm$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1XyKnu/1)

Another way could be matching the `/` right before the digits.

```
^https://www\.mywebsite\.com/[A-Za-z0-9_.~/-]+/([0-9]{9,10})\.htm$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rDUgcV/1)

If there can also be chars a-zA-Z or an underscoe before the digits and a lookbehind is supported, you could also assert that there is not a digit before `(?<!\d)`

```
^https://www\.mywebsite\.com/[A-Za-z0-9_.~/-]+(?<!\d)([0-9]{9,10})\.htm$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/10T0oJ/1)

Answer (score 3):

As per @TheFourthBird, you are missing a match on the forward slash. Maybe a slightly different approach to yours would be a non-capturing group:

```
^https://www.mywebsite.com/(?:[^/]+/)+(\d{9,10}).htm$
```

Answer (score 1):

One more approach. This gets all the numbers between `/` and `htm`

```
(\d+)(?=\.htm)
```

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/Wfs2ae/1)

Comment: Just a small note as I can't speak for OP. But wouldn't this negate the fact that `https://www.mywebsite.com/` is in there for a reason? Also, there must be exactly 9-10 digits. If those are no requirements then yes, your way is easiest for sure =).

Comment: He mentioned "I would like to extract this number using a Regex", hence the answer. Maybe, you are right. If OP is of your view, i will delete my answer. Thanks.

Comment: No worries @moys, you got my upvote. It was just something I noticed. I do agree you can read the question the way you interpreted. OP could have been clearer. However, I still think there should at least be the check for website name =)